# How do you properly define a PyTorch CNN model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I'm new to PyTorch coming from TensorFlow. I have a dataset of, say, Cats and Dogs, and I want to be able to train a custom CNN model in PyTorch. For my model, I'll use a fairly similar implementation of LeNet5's architecture:

```py
class LeNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(LeNet, self).__init__()
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        self.pool = nn.AvgPool2d(kernel_size=(2, 2), stride=(2, 2))
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(
            in_channels=1,
            out_channels=6,
            kernel_size=(5, 5),
            stride=(1, 1),
            padding=(0, 0),
        )
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(
            in_channels=6,
            out_channels=16,
            kernel_size=(5, 5),
            stride=(1, 1),
            padding=(0, 0),
        )
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(
            in_channels=16,
            out_channels=120,
            kernel_size=(5, 5),
            stride=(1, 1),
            padding=(0, 0),
        )
        self.linear1 = nn.Linear(120, 84)
        self.linear2 = nn.Linear(84, 10)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.relu(self.conv1(x))
        x = self.pool(x)
        x = self.relu(self.conv2(x))
        x = self.pool(x)
        x = self.relu(
            self.conv3(x)
        )  # num_examples x 120 x 1 x 1 --> num_examples x 120
        x = x.reshape(x.shape[0], -1)
        x = self.relu(self.linear1(x))
        x = self.linear2(x)
        return x
```

Now, because this is the LeNet architecture, I know that my images will have to be (1, 32, 32) or grayscale images of size (32, 32). But supposing I want to try training on images of size (64, 64), suddenly I get a

```py
RuntimeError: mat1 dim 1 must match mat2 dim 0
```

My question is: how do I know how to define my models so that they "dynamically" work with any image size I choose.
What I miss about TensorFlow, was that `Input` had an `input_size` parameter that defined the input size of the model. As far as I know, PyTorch doesn't have it.
Any help please?

Comment: After your last convolution, you get 120 feature maps of size 1x1, which is why your first dense layer as 120 inputs. If you change the input image size to 64x64, the feature maps will not be 1x1 but 9x9 (empirically, might be something else), so you'd need 480 inputs for the first linear layer. You need to change this accordingly depending on the image size or use something like an [`AdaptiveAvgPool`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d.html#torch.nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d).

Comment: How did you get the 1x1 size?

Comment: It has to be 1x1 because you're then reshaping and giving it to `linear1` which expects 120. If it was not 120x1x1, this would fail. You can check by feeding a `1x1x32x32` tensor to the first part of the network and see that the output shape is `1x120x1x1`. If you then feed a `1x1x64x64` you'll get a `1x120x9x9` output. If you want to find the actual size, you need to calculate it using the convolution and pooling operations that are described in the torch documentation.

Comment: I believe using a flatten layer between the `conv`s and the `dense`s should solve that..

Comment: So the `RuntimeError` (above) happens when I try to flatten and forward through the linear layer?

Comment: Yes, it happens when you try to feed the output of your `reshape` to the input of the `linear`.

Comment: @aim97 The `reshape` is already flattening, but unlike in tensorflow, the dense layer in Pytorch are built for a specific number of inputs, which here is 120, but depending on the input size of the "flatten", you will not get 120 (e.g. with 64x64 as inputs you will get 9720).

Comment: @ozeliger Tensorflow hides most of this for you when you build the model because it automatically computes the input shape of a layer based on the output shape of the previous one. This has some advantages but can hide some issues. For instance, here with 32x32 inputs you get a dense layer of 120 -> 84, so about 10k parameters. If you switch to 64x64 inputs, you get a dense layer of (empirically) 9720 -> 84, so about 800k parameters.

Comment: Okay, so suppose I want to train on a different sized img size, I only need to tweak the linear layer inputs/outputs all things being the same, right?

Comment: pytorch does not check for input size, but rather the channels in this case 1, based on the first conv layer